# NOT NULL clause in a SQL SERVER check constraint

Tags: sql-server

I was surpised to see that after creating this check constraint (in SQL server):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MYTABLE]
ADD CONSTRAINT MyConstraint
CHECK (MyColumn >0);
```

I was able to add an element with a NULL value:

```
insert into dbo.MYTABLE(MyColumn) values(NULL);
```

... which is actually what I wanted to prevent :)

I had to modify my constraint to :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MYTABLE]
ADD CONSTRAINT MyConstraint
CHECK (MyColumn IS NOT NULL);
```

This second version correctly prevents me to insert an element with MyColumn = NULL.

Yes in this very exemple, I could have set MyColumn to 'NOT NULL'.
But my real problem includes other conditions where MyColumn could be null that had to be included into the constraint. I narrowed my problem to the code below which actually does not seem logical to me.

It looks SQL SERVER considers a NULL value as > 0??
However that is not the case when you run:

```
SELECT * from MyTable where MyColumn >0;
```

It propoerly excludes the NULL value. So why then would the check constraint behave differently???

Comment: So far everyone does a poor job of explaining. A constraint must evaluate to FALSE to reject rows. A boolean expresssion evaluates to one of 3 values - true, false, or unknown. When you compare NULL to anything, the result is unknown. Therefore, the insert of a null value is accepted because the constraint did NOT evaluate to false. But you're doing it wrong in the first place - as already explained.

Comment: That is now crystal clear. Thx a ton SMor. Want to make this an answer so I can label it as "best answer"?

Answer (score 3):

No sql server considers a NULL to be NULL. If you want to prevent a NULL from being inserted then make the column NOT NULL. Any type of equality check against a NULL value will always return NULL. It can't be greater than 0, less than 0 or equals 0 because the value is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) article about `NULL` in sql server.

You where condition or check constraint do exactly what you tell to do! You have to `is not null` or `is null` in your `WHERE` condition to exclude or include them respectively. your query `SELECT * from MyTable where MyColumn >0;` is excluding the `NULL` records because the condition does not satisfy for `NULL>0`. To make it explicit, you can write this as :

```
SELECT * from MyTable where MyColumn > 0 and MyColumn is not null;
```

It will produce same result, but it is more readable to use **NULL**. Simply you have to handle `NULL` explicitly always because it means **UNDEFINED/UNKNOWN**

Answer (score 0):

NULL is not comparable to anything else (and it is not 0 or '' etc.), so any comparison results in false:

```
DECLARE @Null int = NULL

PRINT CASE WHEN 1 > @Null THEN '1 is greater than NULL' ELSE '1 is less than or equal NULL' END
PRINT CASE WHEN 1 < @Null THEN '1 is less than NULL' ELSE '1 is greater than or equal NULL' END
PRINT CASE WHEN 1 = @Null THEN '1 is NULL' ELSE '1 is not NULL' END
```

results in

```
1 is less than or equal NULL
1 is greater than or equal NULL
1 is not NULL
```

In a select query you don't get values when the where condition references a field with a NULL value. None of the queries

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn > 0
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn < 0
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = 0
```

will return any rows with a NULL value in "MyColumn", so you have to include the NULL values by

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn > 0 OR MyColumn IS NULL
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn < 0 OR MyColumn IS NULL
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = 0 OR MyColumn IS NULL
```

Comment: Exactly! So why does the first version of the check constraint allows to insert an element? It should evaluate NULL > 0 as false and thus prevent the element creation!

Comment: Because NULL < 0 is false as well, You can't compare NULL with an integer, because it is not greater, less or equal to any number. The constraint must be "[...] CHECK (MyColumn > 0 AND MyColumn IS NOT NULL)"

Answer (score 0):

Good catch man! but check constraint works that way, read along.

The CHECK constraints reject values that cause the Boolean expression evaluates to FALSE.
Because NULL evaluates to UNKNOWN, it can be used in the expression to bypass a constraint.

For example, you can insert a product whose unit price is NULL as shown in the following query:

```
INSERT INTO test.products(product_name, unit_price)
VALUES ('Another Awesome Bike', NULL);
```

NULL is not a really value but it indicates missing tuple value.

Please try read NULL [here](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-what-is-a-null-value/).

Source: http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-check-constraint/#targetText=SQL%20Server%20CHECK%20constraint%20and,expression%20to%20bypass%20a%20constraint.&targetText=SQL%20Server%20inserted%20NULL%20into,did%20not%20return%20an%20error.

See this [stackoverflow](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158407/check-constraint-on-nullable-data-how-to-approach) answer as well.